# Computing the Fenchel Conjugate of $f(x) = -\sqrt{a^{2} - x^{2}}$

Tags: convex-analysis

I am trying to learn some convex anaylsis and have just met the concept of Fenchel Conjugates in Rockafellar's book. On page 106 in the section titled "Duality Correspondences" he gives the following example of a function and its conjugate

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
      -\sqrt{a^{2} - x^{2}} & \text{if  }|x| \leq a, a \geq 0 \\
      + \infty  & \text{if  } |x| > a
\end{cases}
$$

$$
f^{*}(z) = a\sqrt{1 + z^{2}}
$$

How is this normally shown? Do I simply need to take the derivative of the conjugate and find the $x$ which corresponds to the supremum, then substitute it back in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, we have $f^*(z) = \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\sup} \: zx - f(x)$. 
Since $f(x) = +\infty$ for $\left\lvert x \right\rvert > a$, we can restrict the sup to $\left\lvert x \right\rvert \leq a \implies f^*(z) = \underset{\left\lvert x \right\rvert \leq a}{\sup} \: zx + \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$. 
Letting $y = \frac{x}{a}$, we get $f^*(z) = a \left(\underset{\left\lvert y \right\rvert \leq 1}{\sup} \: zy + \sqrt{1 - y^2}\right)$. 
Substituting $y = \sin(\theta)$, we obtain $f^*(z) = a \left(\underset{\theta}{\sup} \: z\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)\right)$. 
Noting that $z\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta) = \sqrt{1+z^2} \cos(\phi)$ for some appropriately defined $\phi$, we deduce that $f^*(z) = a\sqrt{1+z^2}$.